# Creating an interface class with a function that takes unknown amount of arguments in C++

Tags: oop, c++11, templates, polymorphism

I want to create an interface class "TaskInterface" to use polymorphism later on.
Implement some specific class "ConcreteTaskExecutor" with known parameters at compile time.
After that I want to send a pointer to TaskInterface to some other class and in there call that "executeTask" function which was virtual with unknown number of parameters.

for example I have the following code:

`

```
// Interface class with variadic template
class TaskExecutorInterface {
   public:
    // Pure virtual function with variadic template
    template <typename... Params>
    virtual void executeTask(Params&&... params) const = 0;

    // Virtual destructor
    virtual ~TaskExecutorInterface() = default;
};

// Derived class implementing the interface with specific types
class ConcreteTaskExecutor : public TaskExecutorInterface {
  public:
     // Override the function with specific types
     void executeTask(int arg1, double arg2, const char* arg3) const override {
         std::cout << "ConcreteTaskExecutor::executeTask called with parameters: "
                   << arg1 << ", " << arg2 << ", " << arg3 << std::endl;
       }
};

// Another class that takes a pointer to TaskExecutorInterface in its constructor
class AnotherClass {
  public:
   // Constructor accepting a pointer to TaskExecutorInterface
    explicit AnotherClass(const TaskExecutorInterface* executor) : taskExecutorPtr(executor) {}

   // Function to use the TaskExecutorInterface
    template <typename... Params>
    void performTask(Params&&... params) const {
        if (taskExecutorPtr) {
            taskExecutorPtr->executeTask(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
        } else {
            std::cout << "TaskExecutorInterface pointer is null." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    private:
    const TaskExecutorInterface* taskExecutorPtr;
    };

int main() {
    // Create an instance of ConcreteTaskExecutor
    ConcreteTaskExecutor concreteExecutor;

    // Create an instance of AnotherClass with a pointer to ConcreteTaskExecutor
    AnotherClass anotherClass(&concreteExecutor);

    // Call performTask to use the TaskExecutorInterface
    anotherClass.performTask(42, 3.14, "Hello");

    return 0;
    }
```

`

but then I get the error that "member function templates cannot be virtual"
so I tried the following:

`

```
class TaskExecutorInterface {
  public:
   // Pure virtual function
   virtual void executeTask() const = 0;

   // Virtual destructor
   virtual ~TaskExecutorInterface() = default;
  };

// Derived class implementing the interface with specific types
class ConcreteTaskExecutor : public TaskExecutorInterface {
  public:
   // Overload the function with specific types
   void executeTask(int arg1, double arg2, const char* arg3) const {
       std::cout << "ConcreteTaskExecutor::executeTask called with parameters: "
                 << arg1 << ", " << arg2 << ", " << arg3 << std::endl;
   }

   // Implement the interface by delegating to the overloaded function
   void executeTask() const override {
       executeTask(0, 0.0, ""); // Provide default values or handle as needed
   }
};

// Another class that takes a pointer to TaskExecutorInterface in its constructor
class AnotherClass {
  public:
   // Constructor accepting a pointer to TaskExecutorInterface
    explicit AnotherClass(const TaskExecutorInterface* executor) : taskExecutorPtr(executor) {}

   // Function to use the TaskExecutorInterface
    template <typename... Params>
    void performTask(Params&&... params) const {
        if (taskExecutorPtr) {
            // Call the overloaded function with specific types
            taskExecutorPtr->executeTask(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
        } else {
            std::cout << "TaskExecutorInterface pointer is null." << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
  const TaskExecutorInterface* taskExecutorPtr;
};

int main() {
   // Create an instance of ConcreteTaskExecutor
   ConcreteTaskExecutor concreteExecutor;

   // Create an instance of AnotherClass with a pointer to ConcreteTaskExecutor
   AnotherClass anotherClass(&concreteExecutor);

   // Call performTask to use the TaskExecutorInterface
   anotherClass.performTask(42, 3.14, "Hello");

   return 0;
   }
```

`

but then I get the error that executeTask recieved unexpected amount of parameters.
because in the interface class it has 0 parameters and in the inherited class it has 3 of them.

is there a way to implement something like this in C++11?

Answer (score 0):

About your first code, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template):

> A member function template cannot be virtual, and a member function
> template in a derived class cannot override a virtual member function
> from the base class.

And about your second code, see [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449141/why-overridden-method-hides-all-methods-with-same-name-regardless-of-its-argumen) in S.O about name hiding.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question but still is helpful thankyou.